# Python os.makedirs invokes 'FileNotFound' error

Tags: python, python-3.x

OS : Windows 10
Python 3.9.6

When I try 'os.makedirs' to make some dirs in 'Documents', it invokes 'FileNotFound' error which is occurred when one tries 'os.mkdir' with a path that does not have existed root dirs.
But it is weird that if I run the script via IDLE then it is okay..
What can I do to make it run in CMD or other environments(like VS Code)?

```
import os
os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\my account\\Documents\\aaaaa\\bbbb')
```

SUMMARY

- Run the script from IDLE : OK
- Run the script from CMD : FileNotFoundError
- Run the script from VS CODE : FileNotFoundError
- Run the script from anywhere but different dir paths (not 'Documents') : OK

ERROR TRACEBACK

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\my account\Desktop\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\my account\\Documents\\aaaa\\bbbb')
  File "C:\Users\my account\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "C:\Users\my account\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\my account\\Documents\\aaaa'
```

ADDITION

I Found that 'Documents' is not writable. Below code also invokes the same error. But I suppose if the permission is the matter then 'a permission error' should be invoked.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\my account\Documents\sample_text.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("any text")
```

Comment: Please provide the **complete** error traceback for a case where you got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps

```
import os    
path = r'C:\\Users\\my account\\Documents\\aaaaa\\bbbb'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
```

Comment: Same error for r'C:\\Users\\my account\\Documents\\aaaaa\\bbbb' neither for r'C:\Users\my account\Documents\aaaaa\bbbb'

Comment: does aaaaa dir exits

Comment: Probably looks like permission error have you tried  r'C:\\Users\\yourusername\\Documents\\aaaaa\\bbbb' also try adiding os.umask(0) once

Comment: @Lakpa2. No. But ''' os.makedirs(r'C:\\Users\\my account\\Documents\\aaaaa) ''' does not work neither. What does 'umask' do? I can't find detail for it.